# MySQL UPDATE not working when text similar

Tags: mysql

**UPDATE:  It looks like MySQL ignores the trailing space on the query 'Media Services '**

I have the following code:

```
SELECT * from table WHERE company = 'Media Services '
```

This brings back 132 rows (**note the space at the end of the company name**).  I need to remove this space, so I have tried using the following code:

```
UPDATE table SET company = 'Media Services' WHERE company = 'Media Services '
```

The output is `0 rows affected` - trying to understand why that might be?

Any ideas and suggestions as I don't really want to manually change 132 records.

Comment: Works for me. You may try `UPDATE table SET company = 'Media Services' WHERE company like 'Media Services?'`

Comment: What is the datatype of the `company` column? MySQL normally ignores trailing spaces in `CHAR` and `VARCHAR` data.

Comment: What version of MySQL? The documentation says _Before MySQL 5.0.3, trailing spaces are removed from values when they are stored into a VARCHAR column_

Comment: When I run `SELECT * from table WHERE company = 'Media Services '` it returns 132 rows and when I edit one, the space is indeed there.  Using 5.1.70 I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure but try using `LIKE` operator instead like

```
UPDATE table SET company = 'Media Services' 
WHERE company LIKE 'Media Services%'
```

Per your latest comment, it's my strong guess that there is no trailing spaces in company value as. it's just that when you say `where company = 'Media Services '`; it just ignores the trailing space and gives you the matched result.

So essentially, update never happens since there is nothing to update actually and so `UPDATE` says `0 rows affected`.

Comment: Tried that - no joy - still returned `0 rows affected`

Comment: @Homer_J, in that case it's my strong guess there is no trailing spaces in company value as. it's just that when you say `where company = 'Media Services '`; it just ignores the trailing space and gives you the matched result. So, update never happens since nothing to update actually.

Comment: @SujanSivagurunathan, NO; `%` is meant to catch that space/whatever after.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

> UPDATE table SET company = RTRIM(company)

This will remove all trailing spaces
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_rtrim

Comment: That will do it for all rows, not necessarily what OP wants.

Comment: Well, I think that there will be no company which should have trailing spaces on the table, if so we could add the LIKE as Rahul suggested

Comment: OK, this is weird - that's not working either.  I've no idea what is going on.

Comment: Is your company field defined as VARCHAR?

Answer (score 0):

The function that should work if select returns results, would be:

`UPDATE table SET company = 'Media Services' WHERE id in (SELECT id from table WHERE company = 'Media Services ') ids` ...

Of course if table has unique `id` field.